# Position dom element without using style properties?

Tags: javascript, css, spreadsheet

A little background first. I'm working on a visual component that works in a similar fashion as a spreadsheet. A content areas that can be scrolled in both dimensions, and axis indicators at the left and top that remains visible all the time.

For inspiration I've been looking at the html/css of google's spreadsheet. I have constructed a similar solution that works, but the exact mechanics of their solution, which is a bit more elegant, eludes me.

The relevant structure of their solution is as follows.

- [Container] Div. Explicit size. Overflow hidden. Position relative.

  - [V-Scroll] Div. 'Content sized', no styling at all using firebug or chrome.
  - [Left-Side] Div. Content size. Display: inline-block. Overflow hidden. Position relative.

    - Table containing headers
  - [Right-Side] Div. Content size. Display: inline-block. Overflow hidden. Position relative.

    - Table containing content

In order to do vertical scrolling they move the V-Scroll div up, as could be done by setting top: -15px as an example. Using both FireBug and the chrome inspect tool I can see that:

- When performing vertical scroll the V-Scroll div moves up.
- No top or style property change can be seen on the V-Scroll div.
- Inner content is moved up along with with the V-scroll div.

Any suggestions for how they might be positioning the V-scroll div? Seems weird that there are neither a top style, nor a positioning style different from fixed set on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the internals of the google code, but I imagine they are manipulating the `scrollTop` of the container div through javascript.  This will essentially scroll the div even though overflow is hidden causing there to be no scrollbar.